# Tag deletion request: field

Tags: support, retag-request

It's not really searchable and there's no really commonality between the questions tagged [field](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field) on the site.

As such I don't feel it's adding any value.

Comment: Sorry you *field* that way, Mark.      I'll see myself out. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've removed these tags manually.